# writing an if-else function which returns 2 values

Tags: r, finance

I am working with the below function, basically will return with both delta and gamma value, may I know between the `calldelta` & `calleval`, so is `putdelta` & `puteval`, how may I use operator to connect the 2 return values together? Tried `&` with no luck. Many thanks for your attention.

```
library(optionstrat)
library(quantmod)


  
x=160
sigma=0.25
t=0.25
r=0.05
    delta<-function(option_type,stock_price)
    { 
      if (option_type=="c")
      calldelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
      calleval(s,x,sigma,t,r)$Gamma
    else
      putdelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
      puteval(s,x,sigma,t,r)$Gamma
    }
```

Comment: use a vector? `return(c(calldelta(...), calleval(...)))`

Comment: Functions in R can return only one object. It can be a vector with multiple values, or a `list` with multiple elements (which can be anything!), but they all need to be in a single returned object.

Comment: Thanks @JuanC, using a vector works well so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like calldelta and calleval respectively are functions and not sure what these functions are returning (values or dataframes).
But, store the values in variable:

```
delta <- function(option_type,stock_price) { 
  if (option_type=="c") {
  v1 <- calldelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
  v2 <- calleval(s,x,sigma,t,r)$Gamma
  print(paste0(v1, ' and ', v2), collapse=NULL)
} else {
 v3 <-  putdelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
 v4 <-  puteval(s,x,sigma,t,r)$Gamma
 print(paste0(v3, ' and ', v4), collapse=NULL)
}
```

}

Comment: ran ur lines and see this msg: Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: `collapse` is at the wrong position (print doesn't have such option). Also printing from functions is probably not the desired behavior.